# saving json content from webquery to a file in python

Tags: python, json

the url is giving me the json output,but i want to save that output to a json   file in python..

here is the code

```
import urllib2
import json
url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20item.yweather:condition.code,item.yweather:condition.text,item.yweather:condition.temp%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%3D2295420&format=json"
data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
print data
```

And the output i am getting is

```
  <<addinfourl at 159473132 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x981436c>>
```

i want the json output and not this some socket address....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`urllib2.urlopen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) returns file-like object. To get the content, use `read` method of it.

```
f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
try:
    print f.read()
finally:
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

`urllib.urlopen()` doesn't return the actual data from the page but a response. You probably want to call `.read()` on the object.